# Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method while referring to a element in chrome to set value

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

I have this error
`Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method while referring to a element in chrome to set value`
when I'm trying to login to a website but getting error `PFB` the code.

My code:

```
Sub LoginToWebsite()
    Dim Chrome As Object
    Set Chrome = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Chrome.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", "https://login.nopaperforms.io/"
    While Chrome.Busy Or Chrome.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Chrome.document.getElementById("Email").Value = "xxxxxxx"
    Chrome.document.getElementById("password").Value = "xxxxxx"
    Chrome.document.getElementById("login-btn").Click
End Sub
```

i have tried `getElementById`, `getElementsByName` and `querySelector` .

Comment: This is tagged as JavaScript but doesn't look like JS !